# Change Tab view after certain time interval received as response from Server request

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, nsurlconnection, viewwillappear

In an application having `UITabBarController`, I want to implement following scenario:

When user is on **'X' Tab**, he/she does something & then move to another tabs. And again he/she comes back to 'X' tab(*say after 5minutes-> this is important as I may change 5min to 10min in future*), then I want to show some message like your 'Session is expired'.

Whenever user comes back 'X' Tab, it need to make server request to get response code. Depending upon that I want to show the pop-up 'Session is expired'.

I thought following way to implement:

In every `viewWillAppear:` method of all views being loaded inside **'X' Tab** `viewController` of `UITabBarController` I will make server request & check for response & perform operations accordingly.

***But it will involve many server request which I want to avoid.***

I am not able to conclude with solution. How can I achieve my requirement.?

Thanks a lot in advacnce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform this only once in tab bar delegate method -

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
    didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Inside this method based upon the tab index you can have your code, you won't need to write the code in several view controllers.

Comment: Ohhhh... thanks a lot.. let me try this. I will surely accept your answer upon it works for me

Comment: I tried it, but the delegate method is called only when user touches any of the tabs.
What about all other `UIView`s that are pushed inside the `UINavigationController` of **'X' Tab**?
For those views again I need to call the code I wrote for TabBArController inside `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: For all those view also this will work, are you showing tab bar consistently through out the app, or you are hiding it some where?

Comment: No I am not hiding it at all. Now suppose application is on **'X' Tab** & goes to Inactive/Background running state. And when application becomes active then as I was on **'X' Tab** I want to make server request & want to check if application was inactive for more than 5 minutes

Comment: Then for that scenario you can use -  (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: yes I integrated that only. But again my question is I included the `UITabBarController` delegate method in AppDelegate.m, in one of the Tab's .m file & in **'X' Tab**'s .m file. I set the delegate for all of it. But after putting breakpoints only **'X' Tab**'s .m file `UITabBarController` delegate is getting called. Program control is not reaching to other .m file's delegate methods.

Comment: you need o have all the code in appdegate.m where you have this tab bar delegate method, from there itself you can check. No need to have code in separate tabs