# applicationDidBecomeActive: Fails to push appropriate view

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller, application-state

With reference to my question asked [Change Tab view after certain time interval received as response from Server request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242816/change-tab-view-after-certain-time-interval-received-as-response-from-server-req),
I used following code to show the session timeout message when application comes to active state

Method in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // to check the session
    XTabViewController *XTabViewCon = [[XTabViewController alloc] init];
    [XTabViewCon pushViewUponCheckedSession];
    [XTabViewCon release];
}
```

Methods from XTabViewController.m

```
- (void)pushViewUponCheckedSession {
    //THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT. IT CHECKS FOR SESSION
    if ([[[ApplicationContext alloc] dataManager ] checkSession]) {
        [self showSessionAliveView];
        //here I can write something that will push a view that was seen last before leaving app to inactive state. May be NSNotification could help me
    }
    else {
        [self showSessionTimeOutView];
    }
}
- (void)showSessionTimeOutView {
    //show activity indi
    waitingIndicator = [[MyWaitingIndicator alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:waitingIndicator];
    [waitingIndicator setHidden:YES];
    [waitingIndicator stopAnimating];
    //push session timeout view
    SessionTimeOutViewController *sessionTimeOutView = [[SessionTimeOutViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sessionTimeOutView animated:NO];
    [sessionTimeOutView release];
    [waitingIndicator release];
}

- (void)showSessionAliveView {
    SessionAliveView *sessionAliveViewList = [[SessionAliveView alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sessionAliveViewList animated:YES];
    [sessionAliveViewList release];
}
```

My question is:

It(`pushViewUponCheckedSession`) works fine when I used it while switching between Tabs to check if session is expired.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    //if X Tab is selected then & only then call this method
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {
         [XTabViewCon pushViewUponCheckedSession];
    }

}
```

**But it fails to show the SessionTimeOutViewController's view upon checkedSession**
When App comes to active state, Do I need to do something like flushing the previous views. And then populate appropriate view by checking the session.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Releasing XTabViewCon just after you method calling is dangerous no ?

Comment: I checked it by moving release stmt to dealloc method. SUCCESS. :)

YOU CAN PUT IT AS AN ANSWER. I WILL ACCEPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Releasing XTabViewCon just after your method call is dangerous no ?
You have to be sure that your aren't using your object before releasing it.